# Converting SQL statement to equivalent SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQL query (MySQL database)

```
SELECT distinct filename, DATE(created) 
  FROM FileTable 
 WHERE created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

My table definition:

```
**FileTable**
      id  : PK
filename  :varchar        
created   :date
```

How to write an equivalent SQLAlchemy query for the above SQL statement and fetch results?

I tried this

```
myvar=session.query(FileTable).filter(created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)).first()
return x.filename,x.DATE(created) for x in myvar
```

But it says the syntax is invalid. Please help. Thanks and regards :)

Comment: How to add distinct, DATE_SUB(),DATE() and NOW() functions in alchemy?

Comment: Please, improve your question by specifying particular database (postgresql, mysql, oracle, sqlserver) and including table definition.

Comment: I edited. Thank you for suggesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this but it may results the rows those filenames are distinct in each dates(I've tested in PostgreSQL).

```
query = session.query(FileTable.filename.distinct(),
                      func.date(FileTable.created))\
               .filter(created > func.adddate(func.now(), -7))
return query.all()
```

If you find yourself wanting to retrieve only single row per single filename then you can transform query to fetch filenames and its (in example) latest created times like below:

```
query = session.query(FileTable.filename,
                      func.date(func.max(FileTable.created)))\
               .filter(created > func.adddate(func.now(), -7))\
               .group_by(FileTable.filename)
return query.all()
```

Comment: @Tania Fixed query to use ADDDATE function so could you retry them? I didn't test it since I don't have MySQL in my local so you should validates it.

Comment: the datetime field is returned as "datetime.date(<some_date>)". How can i get just the date?

Comment: It threw an attribute error when I tried to reference a field... I altered your solution to **query(FileTable.filename).distinct()** now it works

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you are looking for magic [`func`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/functions.html) of `sqlalchemy.sql.functions`. Here is an example:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
metadata = MetaData()
FileTable = Table(
    'FileTable',
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('filename', String),
    Column('created', DateTime))

print select([
    distinct(FileTable.columns.filename),
    func.date(FileTable.columns.created)
]).where(
    FileTable.columns.created > func.date_sub(func.now(), 7))

# Output:
# SELECT DISTINCT "FileTable".filename, date("FileTable".created) AS date_1 
# FROM "FileTable" 
# WHERE "FileTable".created > date_sub(now(), :date_sub_1)
```

Comment: But I dont want a SQLAlchemy statement to create the query. I want an sqlalchemy query to fetch the results that the SQL statement would. In the pure alchemy way with sessions and query(),filter() functions..